# How do these SQL-Server-2005 MERGE alternatives compare

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL-Server-2005 how are the following approaches likely to compare in terms of performance for a bulk update of data.

**Bulk Delete then Bulk Insert**

```
--Delete Existing Data
DELETE FROM Foo
WHERE Category = 1;

--Insert New Data
INSERT INTO Foo (Id, Category, ...)
SELECT Id, Category, ...
FROM @Temp;
```

**(Merge Style) Bulk Insert/Update/Delete**

```
--Delete Existing Data Not In New Data
DELETE FROM Foo 
FROM Foo LEFT OUTER JOIN @Temp T ON Foo.Id = T.Id
WHERE Foo.Category = 1
AND T.Id IS NULL;

--Update Matching Data
UPDATE Foo
SET
    Foo.Category = T.Category,
...
FROM Foo INNER JOIN @Temp T ON Foo.Id = T.Id;

--Insert New Data
INSERT INTO Foo (Id, Category, ...)
SELECT Id, Category, ...
FROM @Temp T LEFT OUTER JOIN Foo F ON F.Id = T.Id
WHERE F.Id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are pressed for time (lazy) and you know for a fact that the second form is not required, the second form is always preferred in a production, busy system.

You should beef up the 2nd one so that identity updates (update resulting in no change) is not carried out.  Currently, your code will update a record to itself even if it is exactly the same before and after - in this case, it is almost the same as the first form.

Some differences:

- In the proper 2nd form, existing records with attached references (foreign key hooks) are not broken, whereas the first could break since it attempts to momentarily remove all records.
- The proper 2nd form has less to log
- The proper 2nd form will have less to do in triggers (if the table had triggers)

Answer (score 1):

This **will depend** entirely on your current data structure.  What are the fields?  How many?  What are the indexes?  How big are the tables you are inserting into/updating/selecting from?

Your first alternative has less logic involved, and could be faster, but **it will depend** on what field(s) you are updating, how many there are, what the values and datatypes are, what indexes, etc.

Short answer - **it depends.**

In SQL there is (normally) no "best" answer.  There is a best solution for a given situation but if you don't share the details you won't be able to get a good answer.

Also, `BULK INSERT` is a special kind of function normally using `BCP`.  You can do a `minimally logged` insert but what you have listed is not a `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: Nitpicking on terminology, a "bulk insert" in plain English is just an insert in bulk, or an insert involving bulk (volume/many records)

Comment: @Richard - I realize that, just wanted to clarify it for OP since when you are talking SQL Bulk Insert has special meaning.